# How to insert dynamic row in different html table position

Tags: php, html

I want to echo following xml data in html table using php,

```
<type>Debit</type>
<item>Item-1</item>
<price>150</price>
<type>Debit</type>
<item>Item-2</item>
<price>250</price>
<type>Debit</type>
<item>Item-3</item>
<price>100</price>
type>Debit</type>
<item>Item-4</item>
<price>200</price>
............
...so on
<type>Credit</type>
<item>Item-50</item>
<price>200</price>
<type>Credit</type>
<item>Item-51</item>
<price>300</price>
<type>Credit</type>
<item>Item-60</item>
<price>100</price>
............
...so on
```

here is my Html table structure before inserting data

[image]

Now if you see my xml data, i want to dynamically insert debit items under Debit List and credit items in Credit List like the following sample:

[image]

I know how to add rows dynamically using insertRow(), getElementById("id").But in this case i need to maintain two different position [1 for debit, 1 for credit] so that i can insert them in correct position.Moreover rows are  dynamic, so fixed id with fixed number of rows will not work i guess.How can i do this in php.Please share your idea to solve it in a vary simple way.Please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Comment: you dont know how to echo the value from php to html?

Comment: hello @ujwal dhakal. Thanks for your comment.i know echo from php to html.But i need echo these tag values as table data td in 2 different places [all debits will go under debit and all credits will go under credit inside html table]. that is the problem.More details are given in the post.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this solution. If you use javascript, you use two tables and use append() element row in tbody.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myXMLData =
"
<data>
<row>
    <type>Debit</type>
    <item>Item-1</item>
    <price>150</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Debit</type>
    <item>Item-2</item>
    <price>250</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Debit</type>
    <item>Item-3</item>
    <price>100</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Debit</type>
    <item>Item-4</item>
    <price>200</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Credit</type>
    <item>Item-50</item>
    <price>200</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Credit</type>
    <item>Item-51</item>
    <price>300</price>
</row>
<row>
    <type>Credit</type>
    <item>Item-60</item>
    <price>100</price>
</row>
</data>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$debit = array();
$credit = array();
$debit_total = $credit_total = 0;
foreach ($xml as $row) {
    if($row->type == 'Debit') {
        $debit[] = array('item'=> (string)$row->item, 'price'=> (float)$row->price);    
        $debit_total += (float)$row->price;
    } else {
        $credit[] = array('item'=> (string)$row->item, 'price'=> (float)$row->price);   
        $credit_total += (float)$row->price;
    }

}

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Debit list<td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($debit as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$value['item']}</td><td>{$value['price']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>{$debit_total}</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Credit list</td></tr>";
foreach ($credit as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$value['item']}</td><td>{$value['price']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>{$credit_total}</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr>";
?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: way you use echo when you can echo only variable.
`<?php foreach($credit as $key=>$value): ?>` after `<tr><td><?php echo $value['item']?></td></tr>` after over code and `<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: if you item description has a format 'item-number', you can use explode("-") description and use that number as key in debit/credit array and ksort array after foreach, for the order the elements in table.